# Why equivalent Graph objects yield different results?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0.**

---

I am working with Mma 11.2 for win 7.
I am confusing about the results returned by `ConnectedGraphQ` described as follows:

Mma believe that `Graph[{1}, {}]` and `Graph[{1, 1}, {}]` are the same:

```
Graph[{1}, {}] === Graph[{1, 1}, {}]
```

> True

However, different results are yeilded:

```
ConnectedGraphQ[Graph[{1}, {}]]
```

> True

```
ConnectedGraphQ[Graph[{1, 1}, {}]]
```

> False

Tracing back, one can find:

```
ConnectedGraphQ[Graph[{1}, {}]] // Trace // InputForm
```

> {{HoldForm[Graph[{1}, {}]], HoldForm[Graph[{1}, {}]]}, HoldForm[ConnectedGraphQ[Graph[{1}, {}]]], HoldForm[True]}

```
ConnectedGraphQ[Graph[{1, 1}, {}]] // Trace // InputForm
```

> {{HoldForm[Graph[{1, 1}, {}]], HoldForm[Graph[{1}, {}]]}, HoldForm[ConnectedGraphQ[Graph[{1}, {}]]], HoldForm[False]}

What's wrong?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99524/edgeadd-function-not-adding-edges-to-a-randomgraph-with-no-edges). I think it's basically a bug related to the internal representation of `Graph` objects.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've stumbled upon a side-effect of `Graph` objects being "stateful". They're legit objects, which we can get a glimpse of in their atomiticity:

```
g1 = Graph[{1}, {}];
g2 = Graph[{1, 1}, {}];
g3 = FirstCase[ToExpression@ToBoxes@g1, _Graph, None, \[Infinity]];
g4 = FirstCase[ToExpression@ToBoxes@g2, _Graph, None, \[Infinity]];
g1 === g2 === g3 === g4

True

Quiet[Check[g2[[1]], $Failed, Part::partd]]

$Failed
```

And of course there's the fact that the reported expression structure doesn't actually correspond to the internal structure.

Here's a cool rundown of all these Qs on these different `Graph` objects:

```
gfuncs =
  {GraphQ, PathGraphQ, TreeGraphQ, MixedGraphQ, PlanarGraphQ, 
   SimpleGraphQ, AcyclicGraphQ, CompleteGraphQ, DirectedGraphQ, 
   EulerianGraphQ, LoopFreeGraphQ, WeightedGraphQ, ConnectedGraphQ, 
   IsomorphicGraphQ, UndirectedGraphQ, HamiltonianGraphQ, 
   WeaklyConnectedGraphQ};
Prepend[Through[gfuncs[#]] & /@ {g1, g2, g3, g4}, gfuncs] // 
  Transpose // NewlineateInput

{
 {GraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {PathGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {TreeGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {MixedGraphQ, False, False, False, False},
 {PlanarGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {SimpleGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {AcyclicGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {CompleteGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {DirectedGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {EulerianGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {LoopFreeGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {WeightedGraphQ, False, False, False, False},
 {ConnectedGraphQ, True, False, True, False},
 {IsomorphicGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {UndirectedGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {HamiltonianGraphQ, True, True, True, True},
 {WeaklyConnectedGraphQ, True, True, True, True}
 }
```

We can see that, for whatever reason, only `ConnectedGraphQ` shows this behavior.

The fact that `g4` has the same behavior as `g1` is very odd. It might have to do with the memory sharing of that core `Expression` object, but that's just errant speculation

Comment: Note the [last two steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiABb.png), I'm very confused what is result to this bug..

Comment: @yode Yeah this is clearly an example of the internal structure not mapping perfectly to the top-level expression. It honestly shows how well tested most of Mathematica is that we see issues like this so infrequently. I'm sure there are lots of places where such things could show up, but they don't.

Answer (score 4):

These sorts of bugs can often be worked around by cycling the graph through its compound expression representation, [like here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99585/12).

```
badGraph = Graph[{1, 1}, {}];

ConnectedGraphQ[badGraph]
(* False *)

ConnectedGraphQ@Uncompress@Compress[badGraph]
(* True *)
```

---

`Graph` is atomic and its actual internal representation is not the same what you see when you apply `InputForm` to it. This is why two seemingly identical graphs can behave differently. As I understand, all atomic expressions [*also* have a compound representation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97332/12), which is used in some contexts.  Converting to this and back forces re-creating the internal representation, which will often fix problems like this.

I am aware of several similar `Graph`-bugs related to a broken internal representation.  Sometimes the breakage is such that it is reflected in the input form, [like here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145321/12), and sometimes it isn't, as in your case.  Cycling the graph fixes it only in the latter case.

---

The simplest *practical* fix to this problem is defining your own function:

```
connectedGraphQ[g_?GraphQ /; VertexCount[g] == 1] := True
connectedGraphQ[g_] := ConnectedGraphQ[g]
```

`IGConnectedQ` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) also works, but I would not recommend it in this specific case as it will be much slower than `ConnectedGraphQ` on tiny graphs due to the conversion overhead.