# Why Graph does not recognize chains of vertexes like NetGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, neural-networks, language-design

[Cross posted on Wolfram Community.](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1563845)

---

Perfect logic:

```
NetGraph[{1, 1, 1}, {1 -> 2 -> 3}]
```

But this does not make sense:

```
Graph[{1, 1, 1}, {1 -> 2 -> 3}]
```

How can `Rule` behave differently when called by different functions?

Comment: Slightly related is [`PathGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PathGraph.html).

Answer (score 4):

#### For a convenient notation, use IGraph/M

I agree that the verbosity of the notation required in `Graph` is slightly annoying.

Consider using the `IGShorthand` function from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).  It is designed precisely to deal with this.

```
IGShorthand["1-2-3"]
```

[image]

```
IGShorthand["1->2->3"]
```

[image]

```
IGShorthand["1->2<-3"]
```

[image]

There are other supported notations too within `IGShorthand`. For more details, and many more examples, check the IGraph/M documentation.

#### Why does `Graph` not support this concise notation?

If `NetGraph` supports this concise notation, why doesn't `Graph`? Notice that `NetGraph` uses only integers or strings to refer to layers. This makes it possible to extend the notation without introducing ambiguities.

But `Graph` supports arbitrary expressions as vertex names.

`{1,2} -> 3` in `NetGraph` is short for `1->3, 2->3` (in `IGShorthand`: `1:2 -> 3`).  In `Graph`, this would mean connect the vertex named `{1,2}` to the vertex named `3`.

If you write `1->2->3`, this is equivalent to `1 -> (2->3)`, thus `Graph` would create two vertices `1` and `2->3`.  This is not even very unreasonable. Think of line graphs, whose vertices are the edges of another graph.

The reason why `IGShorthand` is able to use such a concise notation is that it imposes the same restriction as `NetGraph`: it only allows integer or string vertex names, avoiding ambiguities.  This is a tradeoff: quick input, but little flexibility in vertex naming.

#### A side note

You are using `Graph[{1,1,1}, ...]` in your example. *Do not repeat vertex names.* This is wrong and invalid.  One would expect Mathematica to either throw an error or to simply eliminate duplicate vertices, but what happens in reality is that you will end up with a `Graph` that has a broken internal representation and can cause incorrect results.

Here's a question about this:

- [Why equivalent Graph objects yield different results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157957/12)

This bug is still present in Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: I didn't know this was cross-posted to SE. Should I post my answer here?

Comment: @Robert That's up to you.  The only requirement is for cross-posted *questions* to be linked together.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `Graph` is a list of vertices; you're giving it the same element three times (`1`). Graph expects a list of edges in various ways. You're giving it `{1->2->3}`, which in FullForm reads

```
{1 -> 2 -> 3} == List[Rule[1,Rule[2,3]]]
```

So you create a graph with one explicitly-given vertex `1`, and one indirectly-defined vertex `Rule[2,3]`.

Edit: a neat way to see this immediately is by entering

```
Graph[{1, 1, 1}, {1 -> 2 -> 3}] // FullForm
```

`NetGraph` has a different argument format, so I guess it boils down to the fact that the functions are different, hence they expect their edge list in different formats.

/ J

Answer (score 1):

## Problems With Graph Edge Operators

The situation is even worse than you describe and happens to involve a whole handful of Mathematica quirks.

The edge operators have a unique nonstandard behavior (quirk #1).

```
a\[DirectedEdge]b\[UndirectedEdge]c
Syntax::tsntxi: "a\[DirectedEdge]b\[UndirectedEdge]c" is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

The same behavior is observed with any combination of the `*Edge` operators. *These are the only binary operators in Mathematica that exhibit this behavior.* Inserting parentheses resolves the syntax error:

```
In[1]:=  a\[DirectedEdge](b\[UndirectedEdge]c)  //FullForm
Out[1]=  DirectedEdge[a,UndirectedEdge[b,c]]

In[2]:=  (a\[DirectedEdge]b)\[UndirectedEdge]c  //FullForm
Out[2]=  UndirectedEdge[DirectedEdge[a,b],c]
```

...but unfortunately, just as with your `Rule`s notation, this will not work.

Before we move on to the next brick wall, this is a good place to mention that `TwoWayRule`'s two different notations `<->` and `\[TwoWayRule]` *have different operator precedence*. (Quirk #2.)

## Problems With The `Graph` Function

The reason your use of `Rule`s notation doesn't work is the same reason parenthesizing `*Edge` operators doesn't work:  `Graph` isn't smart enough to understand our intended meaning of the parenthesized expression (quirk #3) and instead creates an edge with one vertex having the other edge as its *name*:
[image: Graph with a vertex with an edge for a name]

That the notation `a\[DirectedEdge]b\[UndirectedEdge]c` is a syntax error is either a bug or else someone had to work hard to make edges work differently from every other binary operator in Mathematica in order for it to behave in this unintuitive way. Likewise, not being able to use `a->b->c` (`Rule`s) with `Graph` is either an obvious bug or a deliberate but unintuitive design decision. Since they had already allowed `Rule` to define edges, and since `Rule` is right associative (parenthesizes to the right), they had to make a choice of whether or not they would allow a vertex to make the inner rule the name of a vertex, as it would be if it were anything else, or another edge, as we would like it to be.

Note the irony that `*Rule` has a higher precedence than `\[*Edge]`, and so mixing the operators *specifically introduced to define graph edges* with a `Rule` results in the *rule* being used as an edge and the *edge* being used as a name.  (Quirk #4.)

## A Better `Graph` Function

Here is a function that uses rewrite rules to transform our preferred notation into the form `Graph` expects:

```
SetAttributes[makeGraph, HoldFirst];
makeGraph[edges_,opts: OptionsPattern[]]:=
    Module[{edgelist, seq, postorderReplaceRepeated},
        postorderReplaceRepeated[expr_,rules_]:=
            FixedPoint[Replace[#,rules,{0,-1},Heads->True]&,expr];
        edgelist = If[Head[edges]===List, edges, {edges}];
        edgelist = postorderReplaceRepeated[edgelist,
        {h2_[h1_[x_, y_], h3_[z_, w_]]
                /;SubsetQ[{Rule, TwoWayRule}, {h1,h2, h3}]
                :>seq[h1[x, y],h2[y, z], h3[z, w]], 
        h1_[x_, h2_[y_, z_]]
                /;SubsetQ[{Rule, TwoWayRule}, {h1,h2}]
                :>seq[h1[x, y], h2[y, z]], 
        h2_[h1_[x_, y_], z_]
                /;SubsetQ[{Rule, TwoWayRule}, {h1,h2}]
                :>seq[h1[x, y], h2[y, z]],
        h1_[x_, seq[h2_[y_, z___], w___]]
                /;SubsetQ[{Rule, TwoWayRule}, {h1,h2}]
                :>seq[h1[x, y], h2[y, z], w],
        h2_[seq[x___, h1_[y___, z_]], w_]
                /;SubsetQ[{Rule, TwoWayRule}, {h1,h2}]
                :>seq[x, h1[y, z], h2[z, w]]}];
        edgelist=edgelist//.seq->Sequence;
        Graph[edgelist, opts]
    ]
```

You might notice that `makeGraph` uses an auxiliary function called `postorderReplaceRepeated`. That's because of another little quirk of Mathematica (quirk #5), described in this [SE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38668/replacerepeated-seemingly-omits-some-rules):

> ReplaceAll and by extension ReplaceRepeated are very unusual in the context of Mathematica in that they perform a depth-first preorder traversal, whereas nearly all other functions perform a depth-first postorder traversal.

This is the first question I have seen anywhere that involves a "5 Quirk" answer.

(Answer x-posted to the [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1563287).)